# white-space: pre and flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm looking to make `white-space: pre` work inside a `display: flex` container but it looks as if flexbox prevents `white-space: pre` from working at all.

The fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/silverwind/dhfkap6e should render the text `Lost Whitespace` while preserving the flexbox which I use for vertical centering. Any way to combine those two without introducing a wrapper?

Comment: Please note for your future questions, that code relevant to your problem belongs directly into your question, not just on an external site. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

> The white-space CSS property sets how white space inside an element is
>   handled.

Here you have 2 elements, you have to specify margin or padding on your flex items or you can add a space inside your span tags

```
<span>Lost_</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```css
div {
  white-space: pre;
  height:100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Lost</span> <span>Whitespace</span> 
</div>
```